# Inno Setup SaveStringToFile

Tags: text-files, inno-setup

I want to write in a text file at the end of compiling, NOT at the end or while the installation.

This is my code:

```
[Code]
procedure example();
begin
  SaveStringToFile('i:\Installer\Inno_Files\inno_log.txt', #13#10 + 'it works' + #13#10, True);
end;
```

However, this doesn't work for me. Also I dont know if its possible to do this.
Does somebody of you know how to solve this problem or can tell me if its even possible ?

Please excuse my bad english. ;)

Greetings

EDIT: Also I tried this, but it doesnt work:

```
function logfile(): String;
begin
  SaveStringToFile('i:\Installer\Inno_Files\inno_log.txt', #13#10 + 'the string' + #13#10, True);
end;
```

Comment: It seems you're going to make your own compilation log. Well, there is currently no function to write to a file except the [`WriteIni`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_writeini.htm) function for writing structured INI files. However, you can still [`Exec`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_exec.htm) a command line with the `echo` which can append lines to a file.

Comment: ah right, you mean a batch file which writes into a text file. I'm going to test this and tell you if it works, thank you. :)

Comment: I'm sorry; forget what I said. Preprocessor cannot indicate the end of the compilation. It can only indicate the end of preprocessing. After that starts the compilation itself... However, for your task you can really use a batch file which will start a command line compiler and write to a file by `echo` command, or a tool like [`Inno Script Studio`](https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio) which provides post compilation events, where you could write to your log file.

Comment: I will try this Script Studio, seems to me that the studio is much userfriendlier than the one from the inno homepage. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much, the script studio is very easy to use. I execute the batch file now as a post compilation event and it works :)